# Cairo Matrix equivillant of GlOrtho Matrix?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, matrix, cairo

Given that I do something like this:

```
void glOrtho(   GLdouble    left, 
    GLdouble    right, 
    GLdouble    bottom, 
    GLdouble    top, 
    GLdouble    nearVal, 
    GLdouble    farVal);
```

and the result is: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xmlw could I achieve a matrix like this:

http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-matrix.html

I tried this:

```
cairo_matrix_t mat;
            mat.xx = 2 / (right - left);
            mat.yx = 0;
            mat.xy =  2 / (top - bottom);
            mat.yy = 0;
            mat.x0 = 0;
            mat.y0 = 0;

cairo_set_matrix(cr,&mat);
```

But it did not work. How could I acheive the same matrix that GlOrtho makes in Cairo?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know Cairo but it looks like `cairo_matrix_t` is a 3x3 matrix, not a 4x4 like OpenGL ones. If your points are like `( x y 1 )` (again I don't know Cairo) you have to remove the third line and column of the GL matrix, not the fourth

Comment: Then what should I do to make it work for 3x3?

Comment: But it only has 6 doubles, not 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Cairo so I'll delete my answer if a better one comes.

According to the docs of Cairo:

```
x_new = xx * x + xy * y + x0;
y_new = yx * x + yy * y + y0;
```

When you use OpenGL, the formula is like: (`m` being the matrix)

```
x_new = m(1,1) * x + m(1,2) * y + m(1,3) * z + m(1,4)
y_new = m(2,1) * x + m(2,2) * y + m(2,3) * z + m(2,4)
z_new = m(3,1) * x + m(3,2) * y + m(3,3) * z + m(3,4)
```

(note that for the sake of simplicity I did not mention the fourth coordinate)

So what you have to do is simply match the two formulas:

```
mat.xx = 2 / (right - left);
mat.yy = 2 / (top - bottom);
mat.xy = 0;
mat.yx = 0;
mat.x0 = -(right + left) / (right - left);
mat.y0 = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
```

Please try this

Comment: I dont think it worked, I'm drawing and never seeing anything,

Comment: The problem is also that this OpenGL matrix is built for surfaces whose coords are going from (-1,1) to (1,-1). I don't know if it is the case for Cairo

Comment: float left;
   left = cameraX - ((float)engineGL.controls.MainGlFrame.Dimensions.x) * scalediv;
   float right;
   right = cameraX + ((float)engineGL.controls.MainGlFrame.Dimensions.x) * scalediv;
   float bottom;
   bottom = cameraY - ((float)engineGL.controls.MainGlFrame.Dimensions.y) * scalediv;
   float top;
   top = cameraY + ((float)engineGL.controls.MainGlFrame.Dimensions.y) * scalediv;

Comment: Try `left = cameraX - 1; right = cameraX + 1; top = cameraY + 1; bottom = cameraY - 1;` this is kind of a 'hack' but it will maybe work (again sorry but I can't test). The best solution would be to modify the matrix

Comment: Is there an alternative way to achieve this by doing translate and scale?

Comment: If you want to use translate and scale, simply translate by `-cameraX, -cameraY` and then scale by `scalediv, scalediv`. Now that you talk about it, it's certainly easier :)

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake, try `left = cameraX - scalediv; right = cameraX + scalediv; top = cameraY + scalediv; bottom = cameraY - scalediv;`. Note that this is a hack, you'd better modify the matrix (unfortunatly I have to leave home now, I'll come back in ~10 hours)